# What is the equivalent of grep -r in AWK?

Tags: shell, awk, command-line, grep

I have a lot of source code files in a lot of subdirectories. Normally I use `grep -r 'pattern' .` to find in which files I can find the definitions of the functions I use. What would be the right way to do the same using AWK in command line?

Comment: `grep -r` is an abomnination, never use it or any of the other options the GNU guys gave grep to find files. To find files use the screamingly obvious tool - `find`. I just pray they aren't sitting huddled in a room right now plotting to also add `find`-like capabilities to sed, sort, cat, awk, and every other UNIX tool or to add `sort` capabilities to `grep` or....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two options:

1. Use `find . -type f -exec awk '/pattern/ { print FILENAME }' {} +`
2. In a shell that supports it, like bash >= v4.0, use globstar:

   ```
   shopt -s globstar
   awk '/pattern/ { print FILENAME }' **/*
   # unset it later (optional, e.g. if within a script)
   # shopt -u globstar
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below find command for almost any unix command to run recursively.

```
find <dir> -type f -exec <command> {} +

find <dir>:
```

> look up in the directory.

```
-type f:
```

> File is of type: regular file

```
-exec <command> {} +:
```

> This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched files. The command line is built in much the same way that xargs builds its command lines. Only one instance of `{}' is allowed within the command. The command is executed in the starting directory.

```
command:
```

> Can be sed, grep, awk or any other linux command.

Comment: What do the `{} +` at the end exactly mean?